# How do i represent this cURL command in java on android?

Tags: android

The command is

```
curl http://localhost:port -H 'Authorization: Token token=blahblahblah'
```

I am currently using this approach:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
String authString = "Token " + "3589c4cd8c18f077bf43b4c4b7415d"; // <~token 

httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authString);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I just get a bad token back meaning that I did not successfully login from my android client. However the curl command i post works fine. So I believe I am not implementing the http Post correctly on my app. Thanks!

Comment: what url are you posting to? it won't be `localhost` on the device

Comment: I know, that was just a random thing i wrote. Its a url of 192.168 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your **`curl`** command has the header as:

```
Token token=blahblahblah
```

Your Java has the header as:

```
Token 3589c4cd8c18f077bf43b4c4b7415d
```

You are missing the `token=` part.

Also, HttpClient was deprecated in Android 5.1 and is removed from the Android SDK in Android 6.0. I encourage you to move to some other HTTP API. That could be:

- the built-in classic Java `HttpUrlConnection`
- Apache's independent packaging of [HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)
- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (my recommendation)
- [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

Or, depending upon the nature of your HTTP work, you might choose a library that supports higher-order operations (e.g., Retrofit for Web service APIs).

Comment: well I added the token= part before as well and had no success with that. Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: @yaman: If you control the server, see what the header looks like there. If you do not control the server, use a proxy (e.g., Charles) to examine your HTTP request on the wire.